# I got this message Saying "Windows 7 build 7601 this copy of windows is not genuine"

Tags: windows-7

Hey there my laptop has Windows 7 ultimate operating system, I been using my laptop for 3 years but last year I got this message on botton right corner at desktop screen saying "windows 7 build 7601 this copy of windows is not genuine" but the thing is operating system is genuine because I brought the laptop with operating system installed from computer shop.  I have been able to install Windows service/critical updates every mouth.  Anyway Windows 10 is out to download for free and I like to know can I install Wndows 10 on my laptop with the message at botton right corner of desktop screen?  I would be grateful if you can help me with my problem.

Comment: Phone Microsoft and get it verified

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to windows 10 from a non-geniune windows 7, windows 10 will not activate.

Get your windows 7 activated first. You can try verifying online first, but if that fails contact microsoft and have them verify it for you. They'll ask for your serial number which you should have on a sticker on the laptop.

Keep in mind, that if you decide to upgrade a non-licenced windows installation to 10, it will take up to a month before windows 10 will start nagging you that it could not activate. This is the free "try before you buy" grace period that is embedded in every version of windows. But directly after the upgrade, you can verify this by going to `Control Panel`>`System` and check that it says `Windows is not activated.`

Also, lastly. If you checked for windows updates, you may have been hit by [a patch from 2014 that caused windows 7 installations to suddenly appear to be non-geniune while they really are](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2859267/operating-systems/windows-7-hit-by-rash-of-bogus-not-genuine-reports-validation-code-0x8004fe21.html). It is easily fixed by running windows updates (or manually install [KB3024777](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3024777)), reboot and then check if your windows is activated again, or if not press the activate now link from the `System` settings from `Control Panel`.

Comment: Hey LPChip my Windows 7 Ultimate operating system is geniune, I been able to install Windows service/critical updates every mouth and also thanks for your help.

Comment: You being able to install updates does not actually mean your license is actually valid.  Unless you got an official Microsoft installation disk, with a license key, both are required to be given by any reseller of a Microsoft OS..

Comment: @waynbra [Genuine Diagnostics tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012) provide us the report from this tool.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a certified Windows 7 sticker with the license key if this was shiped from the manufacture with Windows 7. However, if it doesn't, just create a VBScript to get the license. The instructions are posted here: http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/

I followed the steps and I was able to get my license key. Here is the code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
    Const KeyOffset = 52
    i = 28
    Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
    Do
        Cur = 0
        x = 14
        Do
            Cur = Cur * 256
            Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
            Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
            Cur = Cur Mod 24
            x = x -1
        Loop While x >= 0
        i = i -1
        KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
        If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
            i = i -1
            KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
        End If
    Loop While i >= 0
    ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Comment: Here is another helpful link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-recovery-the-windows-7-product-key/713e40f8-b736-4e6b-b7c8-c2eb70e950a9?auth=1

Comment: Thanks Al G for your help and advice and karel did you do that in cmd?

Comment: Hey karel your advice worked, I got my Windows 7 product key, I can use my product key to active my Windows 7 and how do I do that Karel please?